# How to get values from a loop with a break in a function in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

Really stumped in trying to figure this one out and would appreciate any help.
How can I get a value out of a loop when breaking the loop early?

This is a much simpler example of what we're really trying to accomplish, but I hope it gets the idea across.

Currently, it throws a runtime error.

```
//@version=4
study("Test barssince", overlay=true)

// NOTE: run on the daily chart

n = input(1)

sundayHigh = dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday ? high : na 
bgcolor(sundayHigh ? color.green : na)

someHighPrice = valuewhen(sundayHigh, sundayHigh, n) // value of the nth previous sundayHigh

mybarssince(ser, val) =>
    int bars = na
    for i=0 to 99
        bars := i
        if ser[i] == val
            break
    bars
int sbars = mybarssince(high, someHighPrice) // Runtime error.

if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
    // connect this bar (wednesday) with the nth previous sunday
    line.new(bar_index-sbars, high[sbars], bar_index, high, color=color.orange, width=3)
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Was the error something like this `Return type of 'then' block (void) is not compatible with return type of 'else' block (series[void])`?

Comment: @givanse IIRC it didn't give any error. something under the hood just wasn't working.
According to the Pine team they fixed it just a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LucF commented, this turned out to be a bug in Pine.

Comment: The bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your testing day for monday and the location of the `bars` var reassignement:

```
//@version=4
study("Test barssince", overlay=true)

// NOTE: run on the daily chart

n = input(1)

sundayHigh = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday ? high : na 
bgcolor(sundayHigh ? color.green : na)

someHighPrice = valuewhen(sundayHigh, sundayHigh, n) // value of the nth previous sundayHigh

mybarssince(ser, val) =>
    int bars = na
    for i=0 to 99
        if ser[i] == val
            bars := i
            break
    bars
int sbars = mybarssince(high, someHighPrice) // Runtime error.

if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
    // connect this bar (wednesday) with the nth previous sunday
    line.new(bar_index-sbars, high[sbars], bar_index, high, color=color.orange, width=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @lucf-pinecoders !
Any idea why moving the `bars := i` into the if statement makes a difference? (Pine documentation link?) Why can it not work with assigning outside the `if`? Coming from other languages this doesn't make sense to me. I'm only trying to understand.

I'll give this a shot with the real code I'm working with and report back :)

Comment: For the record, the original code would work as expected if it wasn't in a function...hence my confusion.

Comment: ) Good question. I've asked the Pine team. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug.

Comment: hey @LucF, glad we caught it. and thanks for asking the Pine team.
any idea when a fix would become public?

Comment: No ETA on fix yet, but you can follow its progress here: https://trello.com/c/gREtXdvW